# Java - Whats the best method for prime number counting from a doubly linked list using the txt files?

Tags: java, linked-list, primes, doubly-linked-list

I'm fairly new to using java so there is probably no point to rate this page (unless if you really want to, I don't care), so I'm just a student and am not a fan of programming.

I'm looking at this starting code page here and I am stuck with what methods I should use to count the prime numbers. My Java package contains 3 coding pages; 3 being the Mymain (dllmain), Mylist(dlllist) and Mynode(dllnode).

I know I need to input one method at least for counting the prime numbers.

On the following I will show you the Mymain script and two pieces of prime number methods from Mylist and also a Mynode constructor just in case if you need to over see how this code will work.

Thanks.

```html
package sample3;
import java.io.*;
public class Mymain {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  // Declaring variables for "Mynode"
  Mynode D1 = null; //"D" stands for Data
  Mynode D2 = null;
  Mynode D3 = null;
  
  // Declaring variables for "Mylist"
  Mylist L1 = new Mylist(); //The "L" stands for List.
  Mylist L2 = new Mylist(); 
  Mylist L3 = new Mylist();
  
  /* Using the buffered reader to scan the following txt files.
  *
  * f1.txt // The "f" stands for file.
  * f2.txt
  * f3.txt
  * 
  */
  String read = "";
  BufferedReader br = null; //Buffered reader as scanner.
  
   try {br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("f1.txt"));
     while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
     Mynode Data = new Mynode(Integer.parseInt(read));
     D1 = Data;
     L1.addStart(Data);}     
        br.close(); //close file
         
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("f2.txt"));
     while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
     Mynode Data = new Mynode(Integer.parseInt(read));
     D2 = Data;
     L2.addStart(Data);}     
        br.close(); //close file
    
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("f3.txt"));
     while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
     Mynode Data = new Mynode(Integer.parseInt(read));
     D3 = Data;
     L3.addStart(Data);}
     br.close(); //close file
     }
   
   /* Error checker:
    * 
    * Checks if the file is valid.
    * Checks the input and output of this package.
    * Checks if all the figures in the file is numeric.
    * 
    */
   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {e.getMessage();} 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {e.getMessage();}
   catch (NumberFormatException e) 
   {e.getMessage();}
      
   //Introduction for describing the program when it runs
   System.out.println("Outputting all the following data:\n");
   System.out.println("Displaying node count from each file in order, reversed order \nprime numbers and intersections.");
   System.out.println("This program contains: files - f1.txt, f2.txt, f3.txt \n");
   
   System.out.println("____________________________________________________________\n");
   // Outputting the results from all the lists
   System.out.println("Numbers list 1- \t\tNode count:" + L1.numNodes() + "\n");      //Displaying all the numbers from the first number to the last number.
   L1.printHead(D1);
   System.out.println("\nIn reversed order: ");           //Displaying all the numbers in backwards order from the last number to the first number.
   L1.printBackwards(D1);
   System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------------------");

   System.out.println("\nNumbers list 2- \t\tNode count:" + L2.numNodes() + "\n");  //Displaying all the numbers from the first number to the last number.
   L2.printHead(D2);
   System.out.println("\nIn reversed order: ");        //Displaying all the numbers in backwards order from the last number to the first number.
   L2.printBackwards(D2);
   System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------");
   
   System.out.println("\nNumbers list 3- \t\tNode count:"  + L3.numNodes() + "\n"); //Displaying all the numbers from the first number to the last number.
   L3.printHead(D3);
   System.out.println("\nIn reversed order: ");        //Displaying all the numbers in backwards order from the last number to the first number.
   L3.printBackwards(D3);
   System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------");
   
   System.out.println("\n\nPrime numbers from List1-");         //Displaying all the existing prime numbers.
   L1.printPrime(D1);
   System.out.println("\n\nPrime numbers from List2-");         //Displaying all the existing prime numbers.
   L2.printPrime(D2);
   System.out.println("\n\nPrime numbers from List3-");         //Displaying all the existing prime numbers.
   L3.printPrime(D3);
   
   Mylist Ans1 = Mylist.Intersect(L1, L2);          //Displaying the numbers that intersects from the lists 1,2 and 3.
   Mylist Ans2 = Mylist.Intersect (Ans1, L3);
   System.out.println("\n\nIntersections");
   Ans2.printHead(Ans2.Head);
  }
}
```

Here the two prime codes that should output the prime numbers extracted from the files.

- The first one is the prime counter and I'm not sure how to change this one to make it work.
- The second method is working and can output and display all the prime numbers when the program is running.

  the first prime code that works for array txt files but not for double linked lists.

```html
public static int primeChecker(int[] array) { 
   int PrimeNo = 0;        
  for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {         
   if(isPrime(array[i])) {      
    PrimeNo++;        
    
   }
 } 
 return PrimeNo;          
}
```

and the second one.

```
//Print Primes
public void printPrime(Mynode p) {
    int k = 0;
    while (p != null) 
    {
        int x = p.Data;
        if (isPrime(x)) 
        {
            k++;
            System.out.print(p.Data + "\t");
            if (k % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("");
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        p = p.Next;
    }
```

and lastly the "Mynode" code page.

```html
Mynode {
 public int Data;
 public Mynode Next;
 public Mynode Prev;
 
 public Mynode (int Data) {
  Prev = null;
  this.Data = Data;
  Next = null;
```

Sorry for the lengthy codes.

Comment: Are you asking about prime number algorithms? or how to implement a linked list? or read a text file? And please note that Java is a compiled language, not a script language. Java code is not 'script'.

Comment: I have a linked list already implemented, so yes I'm finding out how to get the prime number algorithms that would suit this program. Oh yes sorry, thanks telling me to acknowledge it as a compiled language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overload the primeChecker method for your Mylist implementation of a double linked list, you need need to cycle through each element of the linked list and increment a variable every time you come across a prime number, much like you did with the primeChecker method overloaded for array.  I'm not sure of the exact implementation of your Mylist double linked list but it might looks something like this.

```
public static int primeChecker(Mylist list) { 
    int PrimeNo = 0;
    //insert whatever method here gives you the first node of Mylist
    //I inserted start() to demonstrate, that may or may not be right
    Mynode p = list.start();                    
    while (p != null) 
    {
        int x = p.Data;
        if (isPrime(x)) 
        {
            PrimeNo++;
        }
        p = p.Next;
    }
    return PrimeNo;                               
}
```